# Should I use java.io.File or java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, file-io, nio

Java has both the `File` class and the `Path` interface file operations. I've seen instances of the newer one, `Path`, act in many cases as a replacement for the traditional `File` class. Obviously, it is trivial to move between the two with `Path.getFile()` and `File.getPath()`.

Are there situations where one is preferable over the other? Which of the two should I use for general cases, such as passing information to a method? Is one faster or safer than the other? Other than the interface, are there any major differences or significant limitations to one or the other?

Comment: Check this out to see if it helps out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html